# Zend Framework: Get "invalid connection option "adapter" error when connecting to a PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, zend-framework, postgresql, connection

I got this weird question which I cannot even find much answer online.

The code is like this:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('../application/configs/application.ini',
                              APPLICATION_ENV);
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->resources->db->adapter,
                       $config->resources->db->params->toArray());
$db->setFetchMode(Zend_db::FETCH_ASSOC);
$db->query('set names utf8;');
```

Then I get error on the screen:

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] invalid connection option "adapter"
Stack trace:

#0 /srv/uhg/ZF/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Pgsql.php(87): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /srv/uhg/ZF/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Pgsql->_connect()
#2 /srv/uhg/ZF/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('set names utf8;', Array)
#3 /srv/uhg/workspaces/zpe/library/Tls/Acl.php(72): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('set names utf8;')
#4 /srv/uhg/workspaces/zpe/application/controllers/IndexController.php(12): Tls_Acl->__construct('developer')
#5 /srv/uhg/ZF/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(133): IndexController->init()
#6 /srv/uhg/ZF/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(268): Zend_Controller_Action->__construct(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http ), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http), Array)
#7 /srv/uhg/ZF/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#8 /srv/uhg/ZF/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#9 /srv/uhg/ZF/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#10 /srv/uhg/workspaces/zpe/public/index.php(29): Zend_Application->run()
```

I also tried to omit what I get in the $config:

PDO_PGSQL: the config things

```
Array ( [adapter] => PDO_PGSQL
        [host] => localhost 
        [username] => postgres
        [password] =>
        [dbname] => uhg
        [default] => 1 )
```

When I searched this online, someone suggests I should unset `$config->resources->db->adapter` (of course after storing the value of it in somewhere), but when I tried so it suggests I cannot.

It seems this only happens in postgresql, as it works fine with MySQL database.

I am quite new to Posgresql, could this be problem of Postgresql?

Someone shed a light please.

Cheers.

PS:

For $db,  it exports(I replaced the real db name to xx-xxx):

object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Pgsql)#91 (12) { ["_pdoType":protected]=> string(5) "pgsql" ["_numericDataTypes":protected]=> array(12) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) ["INTEGER"]=> int(0) ["SERIAL"]=> int(0) ["SMALLINT"]=> int(0) ["BIGINT"]=> int(1) ["BIGSERIAL"]=> int(1) ["DECIMAL"]=> int(2) ["DOUBLE PRECISION"]=> int(2) ["NUMERIC"]=> int(2) ["REAL"]=> int(2) } ["_defaultStmtClass":protected]=> string(21) "Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo" ["_config":protected]=> array(10) { ["adapter"]=> string(9) "Pdo_Pgsql" ["host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["username"]=> string(8) "postgres" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["dbname"]=> string(3) "xxx-xxx" ["default"]=> string(1) "1" ["charset"]=> NULL ["persistent"]=> bool(false) ["options"]=> array(3) { ["caseFolding"]=> int(0) ["autoQuoteIdentifiers"]=> bool(true) ["fetchMode"]=> int(2) } ["driver_options"]=> array(0) { } } ["_fetchMode":protected]=> int(2) ["_profiler":protected]=> object(Zend_Db_Profiler)#92 (4) { ["_queryProfiles":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_enabled":protected]=> bool(false) ["_filterElapsedSecs":protected]=> NULL ["_filterTypes":protected]=> NULL } ["_defaultProfilerClass":protected]=> string(16) "Zend_Db_Profiler" ["_connection":protected]=> NULL ["_caseFolding":protected]=> int(0) ["_autoQuoteIdentifiers":protected]=> bool(true) ["_allowSerialization":protected]=> bool(true) ["_autoReconnectOnUnserialize":protected]=> bool(false) }

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

**Thanks for everyone's help, I found a way to fix this :**

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Pgsql(array(
             'host' => 'localhost',  
            'username' => 'postgres',  
            'password' => '',  
            'dbname' => 'uhg'        
 ));
```

Comment: The correct argument for the adapter name is "Pdo_Pgsql". Also could you show what's in `$config->resources->db` (masking any sensitive info of course)?

Comment: @MIlen, hi, it seems even I change the adapter name to the way you suggested, it doesnt change anything.

Comment: @Milen, for $config->resources->db,   it exports an object :         I will paste it in the question post above.

Comment: Offtopic: "set names utf8;" isn't a valid PostgreSQL query, it will fail. Use "SET client_encoding = utf8;" to set the correct encoding for your current session, if the default setting doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can see what is happening, but how or why isn't clear.

The "adapter" option seems to be passed down to the PostgreSQL connection itself, and obviously it doesn't support that.

Comment: If you've found a solution, I think you are supposed to add your own answer and accept it.